# Dynamically loaded <video> not playing in Safari and iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari

I cannot get a video to work on my page. The projects are loaded dynamically, and if a video is contained it loads fine on Chrome but not in Safari. When I inspect it, Safari gives the following error for the video:

"An error occurred trying to load the resource"

Is there any way I can get this to work. I tried looking at the different properties in , but nothing seems to work.

The page can be seen here:https://www.proptogroup.com/projects.html 
the project with the video is the first one loaded after current projects.

Comment: Is your video playing with audio? If so, Safari might be blocking your content until you are a trusted source or you add it to the allowed sites in preferences. If the video is started with a user interaction event (aka not because of `scroll` or `resize`, but through `click` or `touch` events), then it should load correctly.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your video itself - it will play fine in browser tab by itself. Similarly, a local copy of your site appears to play the video ok. Safari has sometimes strange issues with video playing - see for example: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184447. One interesting test (not a solution) would be to move the video to the top of the page so it loads right at the start and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Something along these lines. It was to do with the Ajax request.